# Scrapy Linkextractor or Rule not working

Tags: python, web-crawler, scrapy

I have been trying to get Scrapy's Linkextractor to work but with no avail.
I want it to find any links and then call a different method that just prints something out to show it's working.

This is my spider:

```
from scrapy.spiders import Rule, CrawlSpider
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor


class TestSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'spi'
    allowed_domains = ['https://www.reddit.com/']
    start_urls = ['https://www.reddit.com/']

    rules = [
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=()),
             callback='detail', follow=True)
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        print("parsed!")

    def detail(self, response):
        print('parsed detail!')
```

When I run the spider with the command "scrapy crawl spi":
I get "parsed!", so it only goes to the parse function and not to the detail method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using `CrawlSpider` base class for your spider, avoid using `parse` method as it will break the processing. Read the warning in the [documentation](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#crawling-rules).

Comment: So I commented out the parse function but it still doesn't print anything out from the detail function. And thanks btw I had not seen that warning.

Comment: I just re-read the warning it says that I should not use parse in my callback, which I don't so this should not break my code. But thanks for the information.

Comment: @Vural Defining `parse` method in the class breaks the code. Try to set `allowed_domains = ['www.reddit.com']`, I think this might be the problem.

Comment: That did it! Thank you so much! I had tried this out earlier with: allowed_domains = ['www.reddit.com/']. But when you remove the '/'  at the end of the link it works...

Answer (score 1):

[image]

theres no need to comment out parse... but change to the defaults parse_item... or what ever youd like! point is, parse is a logic function already in a Crawl spider..

In the future when using "... genspider etc etc"
 try "scrapy genspider -t crawl SPIDERNAME BASEURL (NO http/s://www.... IE = site.com)"

Comment: Thanks I will use this in the future.